# cmd.exe doesn't close after starting exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

I have a bat file that starts an .exe file, however, the cmd.exe does not close after the command is executed.

```
start /d "C:\projects" myProgram.exe
```

The program starts and behaves as it should, but the cmd wont close. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I have had this problem before and an exit command of some sort is needed if i'm right.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the command you've provided. You'll need to provide the means by which you're invoking the command (like the batch file or how the CMD window gets opened in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Try using EXIT in your script [link to more info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490902.aspx)

For example:

```
EXIT
```

Comment: `EXIT /B` will only exit the cmd.exe shell if executed from the command line. It will not exit cmd.exe if executed within a batch script. `EXIT` will always exit cmd.exe, even if within a script.

Comment: Sorry about the error but I do not normally use a windows computer and could not immediately test it so your help is much appreciated :)