# Closing a batch after starting an .exe file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I'm having Problem with closing the CMD after it runs a file !
in the code below as you can see I'm using an EXIT command but after pressing Enter the Drive name shows up and this happens again and again
I have tried it without the pause to , it wont work ( I want it to pause there tho )
So i want it to exit the CMD after the user presses the Enter.

I gave a wrong .net framework number to it to test if it will run the exe file or not , it runs it but it wont close afterwards ( the cmd wont close i mean )

I have looked at these questions :

[Close a batch file after running the jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314638/close-a-batch-file-after-running-the-jar-file)

[close windows command prompt after all process completed in the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106807/close-windows-command-prompt-after-all-process-completed-in-the-batch-file?rq=1)

[cmd.exe doesn't close after starting exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734286/cmd-exe-doesnt-close-after-starting-exe)

this is the problem Im having : Took a picture of the batch file when it runs which you can see on link below !

[How the CMD looks when I run the batch file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV2Xs.png)

Thanks in advance !

```
@echo off

echo " _____________________________ "
echo "|                             |"
echo "|       softRAD Loader        |"
echo "|_____________________________|"

echo " _________________________________________________________________________ "
echo "|                                                                         |"
echo "|          Checking the .Net Framework Installed on Your System           |"
echo "|_________________________________________________________________________|"


REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v5.5" /v Version
IF %errorlevel%==0 GOTO INSTALL
IF %errorlevel%==1 GOTO UNINSTALL




:INSTALL

echo " __________________________________________________________ "
echo "|                                                          |"
echo "|  .Net Framework v3.5 found , Starting the softRAD.exe    |"
echo "|----------------------------------------------------------|"
echo "|             This window closes in 3 seconds              |"
echo "|__________________________________________________________|"

echo.
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo "   3   "
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo "   2   "
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo "   1   "
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul

GOTO end

:UNINSTALL

echo " __________________________________________________________ "
echo "|                                                          |"
echo "|  .Net Framework Not found , Attempting to Install it.    |"
echo "|----------------------------------------------------------|"
echo "|          If this Doesnt Work , Please Install the        |"
echo "|      .net Framework Included on the DVD manually.        |"
echo "|__________________> 3.5 client profile <__________________|"

cmd /K "%~dp0dotnetfx35.exe"
pause
EXIT


:end

exit
```

Comment: You do not need to use cmd.exe to launch the .Net framework install. You can just have this code on the line by itself: `"%~dp0dotnetfx35.exe"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/K` in `cmd /K` means that you keep the cmd window open after the command finishes.

To close the cmd window after the command finishes, use `/C` instead of `/K`.

From the output of `cmd /?`:

> CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
>       [[/S] [/C | /K] string]
>
> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
>   /K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains

Comment: Oh , thats it , thanks a lot , I'm still not sure what I'm doing ! first time making a batch !

Comment: There really isn't any need to use CMD.exe to launch the executable.

Comment: can you please tell me what I should do instead ?

Comment: @SinaM.Azad - the standard way of doing it is what Noodles suggested - `start "Title of the Window" "%~dp0dotnetfx35.exe"`, where "Title of the Window" can be anything (or nothing, but you _do_ need to have quotes between `start` and `"%~dp0dotnetfx35.exe"` or else it won't work. Like Squashman suggested, you could also just say `"%~dp0dotnetfx35.exe"`.

Comment: @SomethingDark thanks a lot , I changed the code and it works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Type `start /?`. Batch files wait for programs to exit before continuing unlike when you are typing. Start modifies the standard behaviour of starting programs. At it's most simple,

```
start "Title" Notepad
```

Also `timeout` is the way to do a timeout not `ping`. Type `timeout /?`.

Comment: thanks for taking time and answering me , but how should I overcome my problem ? I'm looking at options start command has but cant find the right one to be honest !

Comment: thanks for the timeout suggestion , had no idea about it !

Comment: I've noticed that the timeout method doesn't work on windows XP just letting you know !